# Interpreting the CDF of a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am learning about Continuous Distribution Functions for the first time, and I was having trouble figuring out why we really care about CDF when we have the Probability Density Function, specifically with the Uniform Distribution.

The PDF illustrates equal probability across our domain quite intuitively, since it was just a rectangle with equal height for values across our domain. Then the CDF would be more of a triangle, with the a constant positive slope in the domain. This initially puzzled me, even though it made sense from a calculus perspective. I was having trouble interpreting it in an intuitive way. I came up with an interpretation, and I want to know if it is valid. Here is my interpretation, specifically in the case of a uniform distribution:

*I thought of someone making a guess for what the random variable might be in some domain (m, n). Thus our CDF is a right triangle, where at m the value is 0 and at n the value is 1, and there is a straight line from point (m, 0) to point (n, 1). If we start scanning across the domain starting at point m, and then moved from the left to right all the way to point n, I thought that the y-axis quantifies the probability of if we have found the random variable yet. This would make sense since the probability of just guessing point n in a continuous distribution is 0, since the probability of one singular point in a continuous distribution is always 0. If we've scanned across the entire domain from m to n, then the probability that we've found it is 1, because our premise is that the random variable is somewhere in this domain. Finally, we've captured the idea of "equal probability" through the CDF's constant slope, since moving across our domain always increases the probability of guessing the random variable at an equal rate.*

Let me know if this makes sense, I do think it does. Additionally, feel free to leave any other interpretations of the PDF and CDF, as I am learning these concepts and it may yield other ways to understand them.

Comment: Yes. By definition the CDF is $F_X(x)=P[X\leq x]$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So it is nondecreasing in $x$. So if $X\sim Unif[m,n]$ then the CDF is zero until we hit $m$, then increases linearly to $1$, and is flat after that. Note also that $m,n$ are not necessarily integers, it could be $[12.8,12.9]$ (so the PDF has value $10$ over that interval).

Comment: I think your explanation makes a lot of sense. By the way, I have always seen CDF used as an abbreviation for *cumulative* distribution function. One of the useful properties of a CDF is that it is not limited to describing only continuous probability distributions.

Comment: +1 to David K's comment, esp. about the word "cumulative" in the abbreviation. Every random variable has a CDF, but only continuous random variables (where the CDF is differentiable) have a PDF. If you are only interested in continuous random variables, then the PDF is intuitive because of its connection to a histogram of independent samples from the distribution, and is analogous to probability mass functions (PMFs) of discrete distributions.